# Distribution of things: Formula confusion.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My book marks out a formula for distributing $n$ different things into $r$ different groups with no blank groups admissible.

The formula being :$$r^n - \binom{r}{1} (r-1)^n + \binom{r}{2} (r-2)^n - .......+(-1)^{r-1} \binom{r}{r-1}$$

After writing out the formula it gives us one question, asking us to count the number of ways in which $5$ different books can be tied up in $3$ different bundles.

I followed the direct formula by plugging in $r=3$ and got the answer $150$. But the answer to the problem is $25$ which I observed was $150 \over 3!$ which makes the formula look like that of a combination. It said about the distribution of $r$ different things which itself weeds out any possibility of different arrangments being counted separately (which comes in the case of permutation). Then why do we need to divide by $3!$

Comment: You are getting answer wrong with this formula or with your method?

Comment: With the formula I am getting 150 which is wrong and after diving my 3!,  I am getting 60 which is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are getting is correct its $150.$

You have $3$ bundles let it be $G_1, G_2, G_3.$

And books $B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5.$

So let $G_1$ contains only $B_1$ or $B_2$ or $B_3$ or $B_4$ or $B_5 = 5$ ways.

Or $G_2$ contains only $B_1$ or $B_2$ or $B_3$ or $B_4$ or $B_5 = 5$ ways.

Or $G_3$ contains only $B_1$ or $B_2$ or $B_3$ or $B_4$ or $B_5 = 5$ ways.

Now let $G_1$ contains two books as its possible.
$B_1$ and $B_2,  B_1$ and $B_3, B_1$ and $B_4, B_1$ and $B_5, B_2$ and $B_3, B_2$ and $B_4, B_2$ and $B_5, B_3$ and $B_4, B_3$ and $B_5,  B_4$ and $B_5 = 10$ ways.

Adding these $5 + 5 + 5 + 10 = 25$ ways.

And we still have to make arrangements according to two books in $G_2$ or $G_3.$

Then its also possible to have $3$ books in any group.

So $25$ is not correct answer. $150$ is correct answer.